# Facebook Android SDK 3.22 connect fails when app not installed

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am currently facing some issues with Facebook SDK 3.22 on connect :

My Facebook instance :

```
private Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(BuildConfig.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID);
```

Authorize call :

```
mFacebook.authorize(this,  new String[]{ "email", "user_birthday",  "user_friends"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Facebook cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            //DO SOME STUFF
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError error) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
        }
 });
```

And my callback Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Everything is working perfectly when Facebook app is installed on device. If it is not app crashes with that message :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:   String resource ID #0xffffffff
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:254)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:340)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:343)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.onCreate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$WebViewAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.Session.tryLegacyAuth(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.Session.open(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.Session.openForPublish(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.openSession(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Unknown Source)
```

Last thing I wanted to say is that upgrading to Facebook SDK 4 is not an option at the moment (due to project constraints).

Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Hey are you doing settext anywhere ?

Comment: @KishuDroid absolutely not ...

Comment: Can you please share your java file?